# Post activities on Google plus

Tags: plugins, wrapper, google-plus

I'd like to make a plugin so that people can post activities on Google plus more easily.
However, the [Google Plus API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) is read-only.

So there is no way to post activities there programmatically.

Using [this link](https://m.google.com/app/plus/x/17t83h6a4w0ar/?content=helloGPlus&v=compose) works.

But it is not user friendly, which makes me want to wrap its functionality.  Before I do that, I would like to know if there is already a wrapper for that?

Answer (score 0):

As you already said the Google+ API is read-only. The recommended method to allow users to post from your site is to use a [+1 button](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/).

Comment: Some comment by the user will be the best. `+1 button` does not seem to have this functionality.

Comment: The +1 button lets you add a comment when you share the URL.